# Use AutoHotkey to launch a game in an emulator

Tags: autohotkey

I want to create an .ahk script, that launches a game with an emulator. When the emulator is opened, it should send `F10` to load a save state to get me directly to the game menu and jump the intros. This is what i got so far:

```
Run, C:\Users\****\Documents\!Others\Emulators\SNES9x\snes9x-x64.exe -fullscreen "E:\Consoles\Nintendo SNES\Goof Troop\Goof Troop.smc"
Sleep, 100
IfWinExist ahk_class Snes9X: WndClass
{
    WinActivate
    WinWaitActive
    IfWinActive ahk_class Snes9X: WndClass
    Send, {F10}
    Return
}
```

I want to make sure that `F10` is sent in the right time. The script should wait for the emulator to open first, am I doing it right?

Another thing that i have no idea on how to do, is to convert Xinput to Keyboard, for example when I am in-game and press LB + RB + B it converts it to ALT+F4 and closes the window, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i do is, suppose if the name of the emulator process is snes9x-x64.exe, then

```
processName := "snes9x-x64.exe"
run %processName%
flag = 0

Loop
{
    WinGetTitle, title, ahk_exe %processName%
    IfWinActive, %title%
    {
        If flag = 0
        {
            Send, {F10}
            flag = 1
        }
    }
}
```

here once the emulator is opened we will check whether the window is active in a loop and then send F10 and stop the loop once the window is active using a flag.

And for the LB + RB + B, you will have to use a keyboard simulator like xpadder and map the keys LB,RB and B to keyboard keys and define a shortcut for that.

Comment: I thought the AutoHotkey could translate xinput to dinput natively, a pity they should implement it, I don't know why but i don't like xpadder, but i have a better alternative, and I think it will work better to for what I want to do is the Controller Companion!